# Substring of a string type TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to make a *value* passed to a function be a partial string (i.e., a substring) in `TypeScript`

Something along the lines of this?

```
function transform( str: Substring<'Hello world'> ) {
    // ...
}
```

And when I then call the function I can pass a substring of that string

```
transform( 'world' );
// or
transform( 'Hello' );
// or
transform( 'ello' ); // Is valid because it exists in hello
// or
transform( 'orl' ); // Is valid because it exists in world

// Is not valid, altough individual letters exists 
// they are not in the right order
transform( 'hlowrld' )
```

Comment: What do you mean by "partial" when it comes to a string?  Is it a substring? like `"Hello world".includes("world")`?  Because one *might* mean that `"Hlo wld"` is a substring of `"Hello world"`, and the answer here very much depends on what you're actually asking.

Comment: @jcalz Like you describe in your example, `"Hello world".includes("world")`. So not just individual letter, they must be in order. I thought that this was pretty obvious in the question tho.

Comment: Would a prefix/suffix type be sufficient here? Or does it necessarily have to be an includes (i.e. any position in the string) type?

Comment: "I thought that this was pretty obvious in the question tho"  Obviousness is in the eye of the beholder.  Would you mind [edit]ing the question to specify that you are looking for [*substring*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring) and not subsequence or any other possible interpretation of the term "partial"?

Comment: I edited the question, I hope this clarifies what I am trying to archieve. My native languages isn't english, so I sometimes have trouble explaining these things, sorry for that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could certainly make the function generic and check if `T` is a substring of `Hello world` via [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html).

```
function transform<
  T extends string
>(str: "Hello World" extends `${string}${T}${string}` ? T : never) {}

transform('World')
transform('Hello')
transform('ello')
transform('orl')

transform('hlowrld') 
//         ^^^^^^^ Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'
```

This can also be converted into a reusable utility type.

```
type Substring<
  S extends string, 
  T extends string
> = S extends `${string}${T}${string}` ? T : never

function transform<
  T extends string
>(str: Substring<"Hello World", T>) {}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAguE8AcFMAIGUCuAjAzqATgSwHYHMAeYWBWaAD1GhwBNVZ1t8AaWY2AFTMuroc1x5gAPlgBeUhSq16AAwAkAb0aCAvko7rlA-KtmwA-J1gAuWDmgA3aBhDAAZohwBjUFgD2OWJgCGOVPbuGAC2RCRcUrz0KvgiABSMZgBEABLQADbp7rAA6kHpNEnc0nwK2kx4WppKMZX6RlxmFtYYAJSwiqp2ji5unt4YfgFBwQBMYcaRMvwV8YkIKLUEqRlZufmFrBzC7Z12wL7+gSFxAOR5GAWnrQeDRyNnaZnu17dDx8Fnqy83h8Mnp3yrze9wBAAssgB3S40a5sAD08JIyJRAD10RjUbAAIIYPCIYLUUCwdz2bxQOCnWqnWBYeg4dzEnyoVBYPA4HzIdJwUDZSA+QaEqgYElkiAwWCnZo2U5AA)

Comment: Can I use your answer in my TS blog?

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine sure :)

Comment: related utility can be this, when you don't want to bind the input string early: `type EndsWith<S extends string> = \`${string}${S}\``

Comment: For a project of my own, I needed following type: ``type RemovePrefix<TPrefix extends string, TString extends string> = TString extends `${TPrefix}${infer T}` ? T : never``. The TPrefix is the part that should be removed from the string, and then inferred T is the result. So I can get `const x: RemovePrefix<'MyPrefix/', 'MyPrefix/A' | 'MyPrefix/B'> = 'A' // or 'B'`